# How can I send an SMS to a mobile number through javascript?

Tags: javascript, sms

I have already looked at the similar questions here and I am aware that this might be closed as a duplicate, but none of the other answers were clear.

I am building a chrome extension where I would like to send a text as SMS to a specified mobile number. What is the best way to accomplish this? I would rather not use an API and I would like to accomplish it completely with JS, and perhaps some jQuery. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

> I would rather not use an API

This is impossible. SMSs do not form out of the aether; you cannot conjure them with code. You need to use either a web based API (to connect you to a service provider that will send the SMS) or a device API (such as might be found on a mobile phone). Since you are writing a Chrome extension, you almost certainly want the former.

> and I would like to accomplish it completely with JS, and perhaps some jQuery

jQuery is a JS library. It consists of JS which has already been written.

> Can someone point me in the right direction?

Search for an *sms service provider*, choose one from the options, read their instructions.

Note that if you intend to provide the service to the public, you will want to make sure that any communication to the service provider is done from your website so that you aren't giving your API key to members of the public.